# Testimonial container showing in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, carousel

I am making a website for a client of mine but I can't seem to figure out why the testimonial box is showing in Firefox but not in Chrome. See the pictures below:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/009c42133e7b05dadfc020e26caf05f9.png]
[image: http://i.gyazo.com/185f6e62d282cc1112b8231e4eb9a76f.png]

CSS for the container (at least I think it is):

```
.testimonial p {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F8F8F8, #FAFAFA) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
font-weight: 500;
margin: 0;
padding: 27px 25px;
color: #222222;
border-radius: 3px;
line-height: 1.7;
```

}

and here is the HTML:

```
<div class="testimonials-carousel slide animate_afr d5 animate_start"
 id="testimonials-carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="testimonial item">
                <p>"Testimonial here"
                </p>

                <div class="testimonials-arrow">
                </div>
                <div class="author">
                    <div class="testimonial-image "><img
                            src="images/team-member-1.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="testimonial-author-info">
                        <a style="cursor: pointer;">Marty Limena</a> Fancy Craft
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="testimonial item">
                <p>"Testimonial Here"
                </p>

                <div class="testimonials-arrow">
                </div>
                <div class="author">
                    <div class="testimonial-image "><img
                            src="images/team-member-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="testimonial-author-info">
                        <a href="#">Robina Delaline</a> Pandamonium
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="testimonial item">
                <p>"Testimonial Here"
                </p>

                <div class="testimonials-arrow">
                </div>
                <div class="author">
                    <div class="testimonial-image "><img
                            src="images/team-member-3.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="testimonial-author-info">
                        <a style="cursor: pointer;">Marcos Bitolan</a>
                        Deep Dish Gaming
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've used `-moz-linear-gradient` for the background, which is a Mozilla (Firefox) specific property.

You should use the actual `linear-gradient` CSS property, with `-moz-linear-gradient` as a fallback:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F8F8F8, #FAFAFA) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background: linear-gradient(center top , #F8F8F8, #FAFAFA) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is there a similar property for chrome I can use?

Comment: `-webkit-linear-gradient`

Comment: Cool. By the way, I'm not sure that "center top" is a valid value? It didn't work in my Chrome tests anyway. If you want a full explanation of the syntax and various vendor prefixes check out the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: @JonathanNicol Hm, weird. Let me see what happens when I remove center top. 

EDIT: I removed it and it works the same. So, center top isn't a valid value. Thanks for spotting that for me! :D